# How to add a .ts file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

It may sound really stupid, but i am going to ask that question, because i believe there are more people like me who comes to a different language and in the first day they can not find out the file type.

So my question is: How can i add a `IVisual` file in visual studio.

When i try to add a new `IVisual` item as a `.ts` file i can not find that file type.    What i need is when i add new item i should be able to add a new item of `IVisual`.  So the how can i add `IVisual` in visual studio 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file [IVisual.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/Visuals/iVisual.ts) (which seems to be part of the PowerBI source) is a [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) file.

To add a TypeScript file:
Right click > Add New Item then search for typescript:

[image]

If this option is missing, try downloading [TypeScript for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) from the Microsoft site.

---

You could of course, just create a .ts file without going through the UI (e.g. a renamed .txt file for instance), but getting TypeScript working in studio is probably going to be worthwhile if it's something you intend to use.